# Copy back in Big Endian

Tags: macos, assembly, masm, masm32

I am new to assembly language and i need some help.

I am trying to take a WORD and split it into big endian and store that into a unitialized BYTE with the size of the length of the word.

word_ints   WORD    523Bh, 0A419h, 26h, 9E5h, 87Ech, 410Fh, 396h

big_end BYTE (lengthof word_ints * 2) DUP(?)

For example i want to take the first WORD of word_ints, which is 523Bh

I want to take the 3B and put it into big_endian and the 52. In that order.

I am using MASM, if that helps.

Comment: What's causing you problem? Many ways to do this, all of them trivial. You could load the word into a register that's byte addressable, swap the two halves and write the word out. Or, write out the two bytes separately. PS: The `3B 52` order is little endian.

Comment: I am an not sure on how to use which registers and when to use them...